# jQuery & moment .js get half (h1 h2) from date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` in a function I am working on to convert a date type such as `quarter`, `month`, `half`.

Given a date, I need to determine if its in H1 or H2 (first half of the year or the second half).

```
<input type="button" class="test" data-date="12/30/2016" data-type="day" value="Day">
<input type="button" class="test" data-date="04/30/2016" data-type="quarter" value="Quarter">
<input type="button" class="test" data-date="03/31/2016" data-type="half" value="Half">
<input type="button" class="test" data-date="07/25/2016" data-type="month" value="Month">
```

-

```
 // On click of a button
$('.test').click(function(){
    var result = convertDate($(this).data('date'), $(this).data('type'));
  $('.result').empty().append(result)
})

// Given a date and type, return the conversion
function convertDate(date, type){

        var output = '';

    switch(type){
        case 'day':
        output = date;
      break;
      case 'quarter':
        output = 'Q' + moment(date).quarter() + ' ' + moment(date).format('YYYY');
      break;
      case 'half':
        // Not sure how to get this
      break;
      case 'month':
        output = moment(date).format('MMMM YYYY');
      break;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmxydLuv/2/

If you have any tips on improving the function, I'd appreciate that as well.

Comment: your fiddle throwing error as moment was not loaded and instead of  $('.result').empty().append(result) use  $('.result').html(result) which will completely change the result text with new.

Comment: The fiddle is working for me and 3 of the 4 buttons work fine as intended. The question is around determining the half (h1 h2) from the date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate `H1` or `H2` based on quarter.

```
case 'half':
  output = moment(date).quarter() <= 2 ? "H1" : "H2" + ' ' + moment(date).format('YYYY');
  break;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kthm2xym/)